# An Indonesian Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: wordplay, language

Ok, so this is a bit embarrassing. I just found out about the whole Vowelburgers™ thing, and I just realised that a Vowelburgers™ Restaurant opened next door. Of course  I had to get one. They were having these delicious tomatoes in their new Double Decker burgers which have **2 consonant buns, 1 consonant tomato slice, and 2 same vowel patties.** But, Indonesians have a very picky tongue (I live in Indonesia), so they had an Indonesian Food Connoisseur come to taste their take on an Indonesian Vowelburger™. Unfortunately, **3 burgers tasted horrible!** To fix that, they decided to **swap 2 of the burgers' vowel patties together and added a consonant lettuce to the 3rd**, and finally they tasted good.

Can you help me identify the menu without knowing the changed up vowels?

| Vowel Patties | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ??? | Tidak jadi |
| ??? | Bekas digigit nyamuk |
| ??? | Benar |
| ??? | Penampung cairan |

Note to clarify: 2 of the Vowelburgers™ are in the order of consonant bun, vowel patty, tomato, vowel patty, and consonant bun. The changed up ones: There are 4 Vowelburgers™ instead of 5 because as explained above, the vowels are combined together, and as for the third, lettuce is added. All words and descriptions are in Indonesian.

Another note: This is my first Vowelburgers™ riddle, so if there are any mistakes, please tell me!

A third note (completely out of context of the riddle): I literally live in Indonesia.

One more clarification: **The changed Vowelburgers™ are still grammatically correct in Indonesian, I just changed them to make it more of a riddle. Bonus points if you can identify these words too!**

Another clarification: People don't seem to get it yet, so I'll clarify: Since one double decker Vowelburger has 2 vowel patties, 2 consonant buns, and one tomato, the swapped up burger has 2 different vowel patties instead of the usual double vowels .

Comment: Finally, I can try to solve an Indonesian puzzle! :) (Well.. Not if @Gareth McCaughan solved this first..)

Comment: Well that's the point of the puzzle, to see if Gareth is a real Indonesian. If he is, this problem is no problem ;)

Comment: Lol, all this just as a set up for Gareth? XD. On the puzzle, I don't get why there are 4 Vowelburgers when the opening paragraph mention about 3 being horrible. Also, what do you mean by mashing 2 of the burgers' vowel? So from two burgers we only have one, and this burger has 4 patties?

Comment: Well, what I mean is that since one double decker Vowelburger has 2 vowel patties, 2 consonant buns, and one tomato, the mashed up burger has 2 different vowel patties instead of the usual double vowels

Comment: And the 3rd is a burger with added lettuce

Comment: I'll clarify it

Comment: And the vowel can come from anywhere? Not necessarily from another burger?

Comment: No, it is from another burger

Comment: So, as an example, if the 2 mashed burgers have double a patties and e patties respectively, then the new burger will be an A and E burger

Comment: Got it, so I understood it right, and haven't found the right answer. In that case you should mention that you *swap* the vowel patties, not mash them.

Comment: Done, thanks for feedback! Moving to chat so this conversation doesn't get too far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123566/discussion-between-anonymus-25-reinstate-monica-and-justhalf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure these are the buns and tomato, but I'm not sure about the vowel patties.

It's a

> **B-L** consonant buns, with **T** tomato, and **N** lettuce

And according to OP, the operation on the two burgers seems to mean that from two burgers (with 4 patties), you take one patty from each, and form two burgers with the same vowel patties combination. But the original two burgers don't seem to be actual burgers.

> [BATAL](https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/entri/batal): Tidak jadi (**A** vowel patties) 
>  [BINTIL](https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/entri/bintil): Bekas digigit nyamuk (**I** vowel patties) 
>  [BETUL](https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/entri/betul): Benar (from BETEL and BUTUL burgers with the patties swapped. So we have two of this burger) 
>  [BOTOL](https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/entri/botol): Penampung cairan (**O** vowel patties)

And the original before swapping:

> [BUTUL](https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/entri/butul) means poked through 
>  *[BETEL](https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/entri/betel) doesn't seem to be a valid word, although it can be considered a [name](https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betel).

Comment: And it finally works! Just to fix up the answer, the intended swap is rot13(Orghy) and the intended lettuce word is rot13(Ovagvy)

Comment: Don't forget the I patty  and you can take away the partial answer part

Comment: Just fix up those parts of the answer and you get the check! Upvoted for now

Comment: Hm, but rot13(Orghy) doesn't have I patty to swap with rot13(Ovagvy)? Where does the E patty come from?

Comment: The swapped burger is rot13(Orghy) because the e patty and u patties are put together in 1 burger, while rot13(Ovagvy) is the lettuce burger

Comment: Hm, so the word before swapping doesn't have to be a word? rot13(Orgry) is not a word.

Comment: rot13(Orghy) is a word, I googled it, though some slight Bible knowledge might be necessary

Comment: And that's it! Checkmark incoming

Comment: Yeah, that's a name, I don't usually consider it a word, though =)